# Mysql: improving nested UNION query with DATESUB

Tags: mysql, nested, union

I have the following MySQL query which runs perfectly. It gives me exactly the information I need.

```
`SELECT g1 AS Nummer, count(*) AS Aantal
FROM  
  ( SELECT  g1 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g2 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g3 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g4 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g5 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g6 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g7 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g8 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g9 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g10 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g11 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g12 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g13 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g14 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g15 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g16 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g17 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g18 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g19 FROM  getallen
    UNION  ALL 
    SELECT  g20 FROM  getallen
  ) z

GROUP BY  g1
ORDER BY Aantal
DESC
LIMIT 10
```

I am using only 1 table for this which as the following columns:
- date 
- g1 through g20

But now I would like to a future like:

```
WHERE 'column name' >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```

I can't seem to find a way to fit this in. Any ideas?

Comment: If `col name` is a `DATE` column this should work. You can try now(), as well: Add `WHERE 'column name' >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` behind each query in the `UNION`

Comment: 1. See normalization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add:

```
where g1 >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
```

just before the `GROUP BY` clause.

You can also name the column in the subquery directly to `Nummer`, so the query would start:

```
SELECT Nummer, count(*) AS Aantal
FROM  (SELECT  g1 as Nummer FROM  getallen
       UNION  ALL 
       SELECT  g2 FROM  getallen
       UNION  ALL 
       . . . 
      ) g
WHERE Nummer >= date_sub(CURDATE(), interval 1 month)
GROUP BY Nummer
ORDER BY Aantal DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Hello @Gordon, thank you for your explanation. The solution you provided didn't give the results I needed. Just wanted to thank you for your quick response and effort.

Comment: solution 1 gave an syntax error, solution 2 was successful but didn't output anything. See the screenshot [link]http://www.pinterest.com/pin/506866133036138369/. I don't know why.

Comment: @Paul . . . Try with `date_sub()`.